# why the cygWin grep gives error?

Tags: grep, cygwin

I am trying to recursively search for  the below string in all my C# files.  Why am I gettig this error?  Took me a lontime to install CygWin and I have been using Unix forever, but this is not acting like Unix's grep.  Noteworthy that I am using Cygwin for my WIndows7.  Thanks

```
grep -R 'new IIntf' *.*
grep: *.*: No such file or directory

grep -R 'new IIntf' *.cs
grep: *.cs: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you calling grep from a Windows command prompt?  That could explain things because cmd doesn't expand (glob) wildcards whereas a unix shell does.

Comment: where am I supposed to call it from?  When I click on Cygwin icon, it takes me to a Windows command prompt like screen.  I have no choice.

Comment: Are you sure that's actually a cmd window, or is it a bash window?  If the prompt is something like c:\> it's cmd, if there's a $ in the prompt it should be bash.  In cmd, cygwin grep won't work, in bash it should.

Comment: does `ls *.*` produce the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no files matching `*.*` in the current directory. Perhaps you mean `grep -R 'new IIntf' .`

Comment: how do I specify my file extentions then?

Comment: If you want to mix recursive subdirectory searching and filename matching, you probably want something like  `find . -name "*.cs" | grep 'new IIntf'`. You can probably google other explanations of this now that you know what to look for. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1165492) is one link.

Comment: And of course, I copied that command from the *wrong* example at the page I linked to. Try `find . -name "*.cs" -exec grep 'new IIntf' {} \;`

Comment: instead of `-exec` you can use `xargs` like so... `find . -name "*.cs" | xargs grep "new IIntf"`. xargs is more efficient than -exec because it will collect the output from teh first command and pass it to grep in a single call, as opposed to calling a new instance of grep per line returned by find.